# SugarCRM: Hierarchy Using 'Reports to' Field?

Tags: php, plugins, sugarcrm

Is there any way to implement hierarchy using the 'Reports to' field in the User module?

My client doesn't want to use Plugins or the SugarCRM editions that you pay for.

Can anyone please help?